# how to stop logs generated from/about my application

Tags: android

I want log collector to do not display any/minimal of the information about my application.

To achieve this I am not printing any logs from my application , and took care to my code should not generate any exception.

But still I am observing some logs about my application in Logcat.

I know this requirement is strange , but I really need this.

is there any way to tell Logcat to it should not display any information about my app..??

Pl. help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

If you want a "empty screen", then you can just create a filter (green + sign in LogCat UI).

Comment: Hi SYLARRR, I do not want empty screen , but Logcat should not display logs about only my application.

Comment: As @SYLARRR indicates, this is not possible. You can avoid logging yourself, but you cannot prevent the operating system from logging.